# Django development server is not serving bootstrap 3 glyphicons

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

In one of my templates on my site, I have a glyphicon from bootstrap. Every time I request the page, I get a 404 error shown in the terminal and no icon. The strange thing is that the page works as a plain static page not served from my development server. Here's the directory layout:

```
-static
    -css
    -fonts
    -js
    -images
    -admin
-templates
    -relevant template
```

Here's the output from one of the failed requests:

```
GET /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404
```

To me, this looks like it is expecting the fonts folder to be in the root directory, but when I put the folder there, it still did not find it.

Does anyone have any ideas? Let me know what other info would be useful. Thanks

Comment: You're requesting `/fonts/` but they are located in `/static/fonts/`...

Comment: Like I said though, I tried putting the folder in the root, where it appears to be looking, and it did not work. What confused me most was that it works correctly as a plain html file, but not when the server is running. The bootstrap css file should be looking in the same place no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

the [`staticfiles`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/) app needs to be configured correctly

1. `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` should have `django.contrib.staticfiles`
2. configure `setttings.STATIC_URL` correctly
3. in your template, use `{% load staticfile %} <img src="{% static 'img/foo.png' %}`

but beware, you [don't want django to  be serving staticfiles in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Comment: Thank-you, but I am successfully loading many other static files, like bootstrap css and js script as well as my own. The problem is that bootstrap is not loading the fonts directory which should be located ../fonts/files relative to the bootstrap css files.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround,

you could place the directory `fonts/` directly inside the `static/`-dir of your app.

This depends on how your project setup is, but for me it works with:

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

template:

```
{% load static %}
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="{% static 'myapp/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

directory tree:

```
myproject/
    myapp/
        static/
             myapp/
                bootstrap.css
                bootstrap.js
             fonts/
                glyphicons...
```

This way both /static/myapp/bootstrap.css and
/static/fonts/glyphicon.ttf are served as static files in debug mode.